# Question about the caption font size of figures or tables using IEEE trans class?

Tags: captions, fontsize, ieeetran

I am using

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
```

However, I find the caption font size of figures and tables is much smaller than the context. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The `IEEEtran` class uses the format IEEE wants for its publications.

Answer (score 5):

It is *not* a problem, it is a feature specific for the IEEE journals. The `IEEEtran` class was specifically designed to use this formatting for its captions, so it would be not a good idea to override this if you are planning to submit your document to a IEEE journal. That being said, you can change the setting by patching the internal `\@makecaption` to suppress the `\footnotesize` switch used by the class; given the implementation of this command, with your settings, you will need to patch the command four times:

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{A test caption for a figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
B
\caption{A test caption for a table}
\end{table}
Some regular text

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Or `\xpatchcmd*{\@makecaption}{\footnotesize}{}{}{}` with `regexpatch`; just for information.

Comment: @egreg OK. Then, I guess, if you agree, we can clean up our comments and leave just your first one.